# DPDK-19.11 linking stating for pdump application results in error

Tags: virtual-machine, ld, dpdk

- DPDK version: 19-11
- Environment: VM
- OS: 4.14.81.bm.15-amd64
- Gcc: 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) Application error: PDUMP

note: build for same in host machine works fine.

CMD: `make install`
Logs:

```
== Build app/pdump
  CC main.o
  LD dpdk-pdump
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/root/dpdk-19.11/mk/rte.app.mk:433: recipe for target 'dpdk-pdump' failed
make[5]: *** [dpdk-pdump] Error 1
/root/dpdk-19.11/mk/rte.subdir.mk:35: recipe for target 'pdump' failed
make[4]: *** [pdump] Error 2
/root/dpdk-19.11/mk/rte.sdkbuild.mk:46: recipe for target 'app' failed
make[3]: *** [app] Error 2
/root/dpdk-19.11/mk/rte.sdkroot.mk:98: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
/root/dpdk-19.11/mk/rte.sdkinstall.mk:60: recipe for target 'pre_install' failed
make[1]: *** [pre_install] Error 2
/root/dpdk-19.11/mk/rte.sdkroot.mk:77: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Comment: requesting for details in steps used. Is this manual build or `dpdk-setup.sh` build? what are the result for manual build with `make V=1`. Please share consolidated details to understand the environment and steps done so far. (it will be useful to use `make` over `make -j NPROC`)

Comment: waiting for updates,  DPDK pdump requires libpcap-dev. To isolate if it is an error, requesting to set RTE_SDK and RTE_TARGET and build an application from DPDK_PARENT_FOLDER/app/pdump with just `make`

Comment: Sorry for not replying to you. I found that this may be because my vm memory or storage space is not enough. When setting the memory to 16G, it works fine. For the time is too long, I forgot that i might have done other operations. Sad :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per the current update from Meinhard, the issue was the VM was having less memory to finish the linking. Increasing the memory the build is successful.